# Xamarin iOS - Cannot create dSYM folder/files

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, azure-pipelines, symbolicatecrash

I'm trying to symbolicate crash logs for a Xamarin.Ios app.  But I cannot get the dSYM files.

**My Environment**

- Visual Studio for Mac 7.4.3. Build 10
- Xamarin.Ios Version: 11.9.1.24 (Visual Studio Community)

**What I've tried**

1. In Xamarin.Ios project > Compiler, set *Debug Information* to *Full* and *Symbols Only*.  Built DEBUG/RELEASE on simulator and device, it did not create a *dSYM* folder in the designated debug or release bin path.
2. In Xamarin.Ios project > Ios Debug, enabled *Debugging*. Built DEBUG/RELEASE on simulator and device, it did not create a *dSYM* folder in the designated debug or release bin path.
3. With steps 1 and 2 still enabled, built app in *VSTS*.  Log showed

> CompileAppManifest: Directory "bin/iPhone/Release/My.app.dSYM" doesn't exist. Skipping.

4. Updated HockeyApp deployment task to publish dSYM along with ipa, but only ipa was published.
5. Created *Copy To* and *Publish Artifact* tasks in VSTS, but dSYM is not created so it is not copied.

**UPDATE 20180427**

6. Returned to VSTS, tweaked the *Copy To* task to use a different *Source Folder* **/Users/vso######/vsts-agent/_work/2/s/iOS/bin/iPhone/Release** and the *Contents* are `**/*.ipa` and `**/*.dSYM/**`.  This worked.
7. Left the *Publish Artifact* task as is but updated the **HockeyApp** task *Symbols File Path* value to `$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)/**/*.dSYM/**`.  This publishes a zip file to HockeyApp in the Symbols section.  However, I'm not sure this is correct. The contents of the zip show:

> Contents\
>
> ---------Info.plist
>
> ---------Resources\
>
> -------------------------DWARF\
>
> -------------------------------------MyApp.iOS

**Research**

- [dSYM file missing in Xamarin iOS app in VSTS #1983](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/1983)
- [Xamarin Insights App Settings](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/insights/user-interface/settings/#Locating_your_dSYM_File.)
- [VSTS Copy and Build Artifacts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/utility/copy-and-publish-build-artifacts?view=vsts)
- [VSTS Drop Folder](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5bc805fd-fbdc-43fa-8226-7c9ef26c79d7/how-do-i-access-hosted-agent-drop-folder?forum=tfsgeneral)

Any recommendations?

Comment: Did you tested with the situation when manually build in VS, can you get the `.dsym` file? Also you can refer this link Where can I find the .dSYM file to symbolicate iOS crash logs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/troubleshooting/questions/symbolicate-ios-crash).

Comment: @MarinaLiu-MSFT - I don't have the **~/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/** path on my Mac.  I was able to get VSTS to find the *.dSYM folder and copy it along with the .ipa file to Hockeyapp, however, I'm not sure it's correct.  There's no .dSYM file, just a folder with Contents > Info.plist; Resources sub-folder > DWARF subfolder and large file with my xamarin lib name -> Myapp.Ios

Comment: Can you share your project in one drive?

Comment: @MarinaLiu-MSFT - unfortunately I cannot share the app due to its sensitive nature.  However, I created new build defs in VSTS using the latest xamarin templates and am able to get the symbol artifacts.  Thx!

Comment: @StinkyTowel Care to share what you changed?

Comment: @lestersconyers - using the latest Xamarin.Ios template when creating a new definition.  It includes a copy files to staging dir task that has the proper pathing for the ipa and dsym artifacts.